# Formulario en PHP no inserta los inputs en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysqli, vscode

Estoy haciendo un formulario en PHP y no puedo hacer que agregue los inputs en la base de datos.

Hice el código de INSERT aparte y lo llamé, pero no me esta funcionando. Quizás ustedes tengan alguna idea mejor que la mía.

[Formulario en PHP](https://gist.github.com/Sudakiita/4dc2b4c34107e26cb30935d0da32f347)

Lo subí a GitHub para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Aclaro que no sé mucho sobre esto, soy nivel principiante.

```
<?php
   

include("conexion.php");
// include("funciones.php");
ini_set('display_errors', '1');     ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');     error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    if (strlen($_POST['aequipo']) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST['atipo']) >= 1 && 
        strlen($_POST['amarca']) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST['amodelo']) >= 1 && 
        strlen($_POST['aserial']) >= 1 && 
        strlen($_POST['alocal']) >= 1 && 
        strlen($_POST['aoficina']) >= 1 && 
        strlen($_POST['apiso']) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST['adepartamento']) >= 1 ){


    $equipo= trim($_POST["aequipo"]);
    $tipo=trim($_POST["atipo"]);
    $marca=trim($_POST["amarca"]);
    $modelo=trim($_POST["amodelo"]);
    $ser=trim($_POST["aserial"]);
    $loc=trim($_POST["alocal"]);
    $oficina=trim($_POST["aoficina"]);
    $piso=trim($_POST["apiso"]);
    $departamento=trim($_POST["adepartamento"]);

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO tablaequipos (equipo, tipo, marca, modelo, seri, loca, oficina, piso, departamento) VALUES ('$equipo','$tipo','$marca','$modelo','$ser','$loc','$oficina','$piso','$departamento')";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);

        // if ($resultado) {
        //  echo"¡Equipo agregado correctamente!";
        // } else {
        //  echo"Ups ha ocurrido un error!";
        // }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola. El código debe ir en la pregunta, no en enlaces internos. Convendría que revises también qué errores están ocurriendo. Para ello, puedes poner estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Si ves errores los copias y pegas en la pregunta. Una vez resuelto el problema debes quitar esas tres líneas. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Te falta el: `<form action="tuArchivoPhp.php" method="POST" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: le coloque eso y no muestra error, le coloque el archivo.php y tampoco muestra nada  ini_set('display_errors', '1');  ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');  error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: haz un echo consulta, y un var_dump($conex) y muesra que dicen

Comment: Pon los `ini_set`  **al inicio de tu script**, antes de todo, incluso del `include`. Puede que esté habiendo problemas en la conexión, así verás cualquier error.

Comment: nada no da errores, y la conexion la hace porq ue la probe

Comment: es que no muestra nada

Comment: Adoleces del problema que yo llamo *programación optimista*: una forma de programar en la que se cree que todo, o casi todo irá bien... pues aquí algo va mal y no estás controlando TODO lo que podría ir mal. Tienes que pasar a la ***programación pesimista***. Antes de darte una respuesta, quisiera saber qué significan estas comparaciones: `strlen($_POST['aequipo']) >= 1`

Comment: si hay un valor mayor a uno que guarde, aequipo es mi name en mi index. Y el mensaje que da es: Connected successfully

Comment: Avisame cuando agregues el echo y var_dump que mencione, luego cambia las lineas de cedano al inicio+

Comment: O sea, ¿para que haya una inserción TODOS los valores tienen que ser mayores que `1`?

Comment: sip, y en el metodo post en el postaman le estoy pasando todos los valores a la tabla

Comment: Pero pero a ver, una cosa... lo que hace `strlen` es *obtener la longitud del string*, así que no entiendo qué sentido tienen esas comparaciones. ¿No será una forma equivocacada de controlar valores vacíos lo que quieres implementar ahí?

Comment: perdon, si, detecta la cantidad de caracteres

Comment: Correcto, detecta la cantidad de caracteres. Entonces, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer ahí exactamente? Es que me temo que mareas demasiado los datos.

Comment: Si se preciona el boton register, lo que hace es validar si tiene caracteres, entonces le paso el insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En varios puntos de tu código estás cometiendo el error que yo llamo *programación optimista*, es decir, algunos programan pensando que el mundo es color de rosas y que todo irá bien. Eso produce unos programas endebles en los que muchos errores no son controlados. Luego el código falla silenciosamente, dejándote una pantalla en blanco, como de hecho ocurre en tu caso.

Cuando escribes un código debes pensar en **todo aquello que puede salir mal** (yo le llamo *programación pesimista*), pero no para lamentarte diciendo *¡ay que mallll!*, sino para **controlar todo aquello que puede salir mal, dando una respuesta adecuada**. Un programa que no haga esto, no está completo.

Veamos un ejemplo donde se controla todo aquello que puede salir y que cumple con unas exigencias pre-definidas, como que no haya datos vacíos.

```
<?php 
// include("funciones.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
  /*
    Puedes verificar con fusión de null 
    al momento de crear las variables de este modo.
    Si tienes PHP inferior a la versión 7 
    cambia todas las asignaciones por algo como esto:
    $equipo= !empty(trim($_POST["aequipo"])) ? $_POST["aequipo"] : null;
    */

    $equipo= !empty(trim($_POST["aequipo"])) ?? null;
    $tipo= !empty(trim($_POST["atipo"])) ?? null;
    $marca= !empty(trim($_POST["amarca"])) ?? null;
    $modelo= !empty(trim($_POST["amodelo"])) ?? null;
    $ser= !empty(trim($_POST["aserial"])) ?? null;
    $loc= !empty(trim($_POST["alocal"])) ?? null;
    $oficina= !empty(trim($_POST["aoficina"])) ?? null;
    $piso= !empty(trim($_POST["apiso"])) ?? null;
    $departamento= !empty(trim($_POST["adepartamento"])) ?? null;

    if ($equipo && $tipo && $marca && $modelo 
        && $ser && $loc && $oficina && $piso && $departamento){
        /*
            Incluye los archivos cuando estés seguro de necesitarlos
            */
        include("conexion.php");
        if ($conex) {
          $consulta = "INSERT INTO tablaequipos 
                    (
                      equipo, 
                      tipo, 
                      marca, 
                      modelo, 
                      seri, 
                      loca, 
                      oficina, 
                      piso, 
                      departamento
                    ) VALUES (
                      '$equipo',
                      '$tipo',
                      '$marca',
                      '$modelo',
                      '$ser',
                      '$loc',
                      '$oficina',
                      '$piso',
                      '$departamento'
                    )";
        if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta)) {
          $msg=sprintf("Filas insertadas: %s", mysqli_affected_rows($conex));
        } else {
          $msg=sprintf("Error insertando: %s",mysqli_error($conex));
        }
      } else {
        $msg="No hay conexión";        
      }
    } else {
      $msg="Algún dato vacío";
    }
} else {
  $msg="No se posteó una clave register, revisa tu formulario";
}
echo $msg;
```

---

#### Post-Data

No te quejes de que ahora el programa es más largo. Si quieres escribir un código robusto, debes controlar todas las posibilidades.

Y convienen indentar, por ejemplo las consultas SQL, esto te permite comparar con facilidad que pusiste cada columna requerida y cada variable. Por cierto, tu consulta SQL es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*, considera implementar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese gravísimo riesgo de seguridad.

Comment: me funciono, pero ahora porque en la base de datos tengo todos 1 y no los datos que pongo en el formulario? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad estoy aprendiendo autodidacticamente, y me esta gustando pero me falta muchisimo, voy un 0,0001% jeje muchas gracias!